# Use scala collection in a hive query

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a scala array collection. I need to access values in this collection from hive query. Can this be achieved using HiveContext.

Answer (score 0):

Define **`collection`** as **`string`** if you are using in hive query:

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq((1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")).toDF("id","name")
spark.sql("select * from tmp").show()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql("select * from tmp").show()
val st=""""a","b""""
spark.sql(s"select * from tmp where name in ($st)").show()
//Output:
//+---+----+
//| id|name|
//+---+----+
//|  1|   a|
//|  2|   b|
//+---+----+
```

Define collection if you are using **`dataframe api:`**

**`Example:`**

```
val st_list=List("a","b")
df.filter('name.isin(st_list:_*)).show()
//output:
//+---+----+
//| id|name|
//+---+----+
//|  1|   a|
//|  2|   b|
//+---+----+
```